# Power BI formulas not calculating properly

Tags: worksheet-function, microsoft-powerbi, dax

I have a visual that I want to calculate as a percentage above or below a target goal. Let's say I have a table head(5) that looks something like this:

| id | Date | Inbound Requests | Outbound Responses |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1/1/2021 | 5 | 3 |
| 2 | 1/2/2021 | 7 | 1 |
| 3 | 1/3/2021 | 3 | 2 |
| 4 | 1/4/2021 | 3 | 1 |
| 5 | 1/5/2021 | 9 | 7 |

And the aggregate numbers show as:

842 Inbound Requests

312 Outbound Responses

Which comes out to a response rate of 37.05% -
My target response rate is 60%.

**What I want to show is the response rate vs the goal, as a percentage.**

Here's my dax:

Measure 1:

```
ResponseGoal = .6
```

Measure 2:

```
Response Rate = IF(SUM(data[Inbound Requests]) = 0, BLANK(), SUM(data[Outbound Responses])/SUM(data[Inbound Requests]))
```

Measure 3:

```
Current Vs Goal Response Percent = IF(SUM(data[Inbound Requests]) = 0, BLANK(),
(DIVIDE(([Response Rate] - [ResponseGoal]),[ResponseGoal], 0)))
```

So my formula is then packaged up to be a simple card visual, but is coming up differently versus the aggregate numbers. I'm not sure why this is happening:

[Visual showing -38% vs goal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tIIYD.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your calculation is:

```
([response rate] - [responsegoal]) / [responsegoal]
```

Which is:

```
(0.3705 - 0.6) / 0.6
```

Which is:

```
(-0.2295) / 0.6
```

Which is:

```
-0.38
```

This should be interpreted as 'I am this % short of my goal'. This is probably a little confusing for users and you may want an absolute difference between current rate and goal rate i.e.

```
[responsegoal] - [responserate]


0.6 - 0.3705 = 0.225 = 22.5%
```

If you are looking for the progress toward your goal expressed as a percentage, then you should use:

```
[responserate] / [responsegoal]
```

expressed as a percentage. i.e.

```
0.3705 / 0.6 = 0.6175 = 61.8%
```

Whichever you choose, clarity of labeling and possibly even a glossary of terms with example calculations will be critical to help users interpret what they're seeing correctly.